# Exercise 12, Section 5.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, determinant

> If $V$ is the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices over $F$ and $B$ is a fixed $n\times n$ matrix over $F$, let $L_B$ and $R_B$ be the linear operators on $V$ defined by $L_B(A)=BA$ and $R_B(A)=AB$. Show that $\text{det}(L_B)=\text{det}(R_B) =(\text{det}(B))^n$

**My attempt:** Let $V=M_{n\times n}(F)$. It’s easy to check, $E=\{E_{pq}|\ p,q\in J_n\}$ is basis of $V$. We need to calculate $\text{det}(L_B)=\text{det}([L_B]_E)$, where $[L_B]_E=([L_B(E_{11})]_E\dotsb [L_B(E_{nn})]_E)$. Fix $(p,q)\in J_n\times J_n$. Then $L_B(E_{pq})=B\cdot E_{pq}$. By definition of matrix multiplication, $(B\cdot E_{pq})_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^nB_{ik}\cdot (E_{pq})_{kj}$. If $j\neq q$, then $(E_{pq})_{kj}=0$, $\forall k\in J_n$. So $(B\cdot E_{pq})_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^nB_{ik}\cdot 0=0$. If $j=q$, then $(B\cdot E_{pq})_{iq}=B_{ip}\cdot (E_{pq})_{pq}=B_{ip}$. Thus $j$th column of $B\cdot E_{pq}$ is $0$, $\forall j\in J_n\setminus \{q\}$ and $q$th column of $B\cdot E_{pq}$ is $B_{1p},…,B_{np}$. Writing matrix representation of $L_B$ seems like a mess. In what order should I write basis $E$. **How to progress from here?**

Comment: Another way of proving it is the following : when $det(B) = 0$ there exists a non zero matrix $A$ such that $BA = 0$, therefore $A \in ker(L_B)$ therefore $det(L_B) = 0 = det(B)^n$ so for non invertible matrices the theorem is proved. Now observe that $L_{AB} = L_A \circ L_B$ therefore $det(L_{AB}) = det(L_A \cdot L_B) = det(L_A) det(L_B)$. Now given a matrix $B$ with $det(B) \neq 0$ you want to show that $det(L_B) = det(B)^n$, then you could try to write $B = B_1 \cdot B_2 \cdot \dots B_m$ where the $B_i$ are "simple" matrices and prove that $det(L_{B_i}) = det(B_i)^n$ for any $i$.

Comment: If you order the basis correctly, $[L_B]_E$ is a block diagonal matrix with $n$ copies of $B$. Similarly with $[R_B]_E$, but with a different, but related, ordering.

Comment: If I write prove $\text{det}(L_B)= \text{det}(R_B)=(\text{det}(B))^n$, would that make one question, not multiple questions?

Comment: @Paul Following are the details in your proof I couldn’t fill: $(1)$ if det$(B)=0$, then $\exists 0\neq A\in M_n(F)$ such that $BA=0$. $(2)$ if det$(B)\neq 0$, then $B=B_1\dotsb B_m$ where $B_i$ are “simple” matrices. $(3)$ prove that $\text{det}(L_{B_i})=\text{det}(B_i)^n$ for any $i$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you for the answer. For $L_B$ I use $E=\{E_{11},E_{21},..,E_{n1},…,E_{1n},E_{2n},..,E_{nn}\}$ and for $R_B$ I use $E=\{E_{11},E_{12},..,E_{1n},…,E_{n1},E_{n2},..,E_{nn}\}$.

Comment: @user264745 $det(B) = 0 \iff B$ is not injective, i.e. iff there exists a column vector $v \in F^n$ such that $Bv = 0$, now you consider the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ that has $v$ on every column. Clearly $BA = 0$. It is a known result that the [elementary matrices](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) generate the invertible matrices (meaning $GL_n(F)$, therefore if $det(B) \neq 0$ there exists some elementary matrices $B_1, \dots , B_m$ such that $B = B_1 \cdot \dots \cdot B_m$. Now the only thing you need to prove is that if $E$ is an elementary matrix then $det(L_E) = det(E)^n$

Comment: @Paul if $E$ is an elementary matrix then det$(L_E)=\text{det}(E)^n$. Is it a theorem? If yes, then I think proof of theorem is essentially same as above proof.