# Exercise 15, Section 6.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $V$ be the space of $n\times n$ matrices over $F$. Let $A$ be a fixed $n\times n$ matrix over $F$. Let $T$ be the linear operator ‘left multiplication by $A$’ on $V$. Is it true that $A$ and $T$ have the same characteristic values?

**My attempt:** We claim $T$ and $A$ have same eigenvalue, i.e. $\det (T-xI_V)=0$$\iff$$\det (A-xI_n)=0$. $T:V\to V$ such that $T(B)=A\cdot B$, $\forall B\in V$. So $T=L_A$. Let $E=\{E_{pq}|\ p,q\in J_n\}$ be basis of $V$. By [exercise 12 section 5.4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4563958/861687), $[T]_E=[L_A]_E=\begin{bmatrix}A & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & A\\ \end{bmatrix}$. Characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $f_T:F\to F$ such that $f_T(x)=\det (T-xI_V)=\det ([L_A]_E-xI_{n^2})$, $\forall x\in F$. By exercise 7 section 5.4, $\det ([L_A]_E-xI_{n^2})=[\det (A-xI_n)]^n$. It’s easy to check, $[\det (A-xI_n)]^n=0$$\iff$$\det (A-xI_n)=0$. Thus $\det (T-xI_V)=0$$\iff$$\det (A-xI_n)=0$. Hence $T$ and $A$ have same eigenvalue. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: @Seeker [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Formal_definition) definition of eigenvalue of matrix. $Au=\lambda u$, where $u\in M_{n\times 1}(F)$. In this case $Av=\lambda v$, $v\in M_{n}(F)$.

Comment: I am assuming when they write that "Let $T$ be an operator on $V$" and define $T$ by $Tv=Av$, they mean that $v$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and not an $n\times 1$ matrix. Because the term operator in linear algebra means a linear map from a vector space to itself. So, the linear map $T$ is defined $T : V\to V$. So, the matrix $A$ is being multiplied by another $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: @Seeker [See](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4565987/861687) second definition. I don’t know, if it is appropriate to say $v\in M_n(F)$ is eigenvector of $A$, given $Av=\lambda v$.

Comment: I agree. I was thinking about this wrong.